# how to understand the term "first course of business?

Tags: meaning

> If your employee enters into your office and gives you cash, stating it's from the business she is working on, then, what will be your first course of business in this matter?

Does this term refers to reaction or duties?

Comment: First course of business simply means the first thing you'll do, be that reaction or duty.

Comment: I've fleshed it out a bit with references.

Comment: that's much clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined below, a *course of business* is simple any action done by a company.

> **Course of business**
>   Daily or regular routine peculiar to a firm or trade, involving purchase, production, and sale of usual goods and/or services, and payment and receipt of money.

([Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/course-of-business.html))

The logic then follows that the ***first*** course of business is just the first action taken. This is not specific to reactions or duties but is a hypernym (hyperphrase?) for both.

Comment: "First course of business" is an idiom which goes somewhat beyond the simple literal concatenation of "first" to "course of business".  It basically implies the highest priority consideration/action in the situation at hand, and is often used in a context where "course of business" would be otherwise silly or meaningless.  Eg, "Well, it looks like our first course of business is to get the car out of the ditch.  Then we can worry about where to go to eat."